# Execute php function on form submit in the same script that calls the form

Tags: php, sql

I tried researching possible solutions to my quest. But what I found seemed to be different from what I want to achieve.
I want to insert records into a table during a form submission.
The insert sql is in a php function which will be called during the submit form process.

The code below works but does not insert data into the table.

Please help me locate the problems in the codes below:
Thank you very much.

## file.php

```
<?php   

$amt        = 1000;
#calculate the total amount in cents.
$tamt = $amt * 100;

$desc       = 'Paying 1,000 dollars';
$xx         = substr(strtoupper("simba-gtpay") . strrev(md5($amt). substr(md5(date('i')), 20)), 15);
$userdata   = $id;
$notify_url = 'http://www.eyohonesty.com/simba/members/gtpay_status.php';
$hashKey    = "ok5";
$hash = hash('sha512',($xx . $amt . $notify_url . $hashKey));
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Welcome | Simba Travels & Tours Ltd | Car Hire Services </title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {color: #CC3300}
-->
</style>

<!-- Start css3menu.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../simbaMenuPub_files/css3menu1/style.css" type="text/css" /><style type="text/css">._css3m{display:none}</style>
    <!-- End css3menu.com HEAD section -->

</head>

<body class="blurBg-false" style="background-color:#EBEBEB">
```

//create a php function here

```
   <?php
    function tranx() {
    $sql = mysql_query("insert into tran (cust_Id,tranx_amt,tranx_desc,tranx_date,tranx_status_msg)
                        values ('".$xx."', '".$id."', '".$amt."', '".$desc."', now(), 'Transaction Started')") or die(mysql_error());
    return $sql;
    }
    ?>
    <form action="https://eyohonesty.com/simba/Tranx.aspx" method="post" name="transfer" id="transfer2" class="formoid-solid-orange" style="background-color:#FFFFFF;font-size:14px;font-family:'Roboto',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;color:#34495E;max-width:480px;min-width:150px">

    <div><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:#FF9900;">You are paying:</span> <?php echo number_format($amt,0,".",",");?>  </div>
    <div><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:#FF9900;">Description:</span> <?php echo $desc;?> </div>
    <div><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:#FF9900;">Transaction ID:</span> <?php echo $xx;?> </div>
    <div><span style="font-weight:bold; font-size:14px; color:#FF9900;">Customer ID:</span> <?php echo $userdata;?> </div>

<input onclick="tranx()" type="submit" name="continue2" value="PROCEED TO PAYMENT"/></div>
```

//collect hidden fields to be sent over post

```
<?php 
echo "
    <input type=hidden name=_tranx_memo value=".$desc.">
    <input type=hidden name=_cust_id value=".$userdata.">
    <input type=hidden name=_tranx_amt value=".$tamt.">
    <input type=hidden name=_tranx_noti_url value=".$notify_url.">
    <input type=hidden name=_cust_name value=".$user.">
    <input type=hidden name=_tranx_hash value=".$hash.">
    <input type=hidden name=_echo_data value=".$desc . " Amount: =N= " . $amt . " Date: " .$today.">
    "
?>
</form>
```

Comment: `onclick` calls Javascript, not PHP, since it runs in the browser. You need to use AJAX if you want the `submit` button to do something other than submitting the form.

Comment: Use $_POST to get the values posted by the form, you dont need the tranx function. Just check `if(isset($_POST))` and if it is set indeed then use all the values in the $_POST array in the insert query.

Comment: The processing page in the action property of the form is not in my control. That page is controlled by an external body. So, after the form leaves my server, I do not have access to whatever data was posted.
Meanwhile, before the form data leaves my server, I need to have the dataposted to to a table in my server.
This is why I need to use sql insert statement in the same form.
I have tried to call another processing page using AJAX to do insert record, but it does not work. Please help me. Thank you.